# UICollectionView embedded in a UITableViewCell ! Cannot present a viewcontroller from the tableview cell ! With a call back

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which is embedded in a `UITableViewCell`. The delegates and datasources of the `UICollectionView` are all given in the `UITableViewCell` class . I need to present a `UIViewController` on the click of an item in the `UICollectionView`. But as the properties of the `collectionview` are written in the `UITableViewCell` I can't really present another `UIViewController` from that. Please help!

The tableView delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
        return books.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CategoryTableViewCell";

        CategoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[CategoryTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        dict = books[indexPath.row];
        NSString *categoryID = [dict[@"category"] stringValue];
        cell.booksArray = dict[@"books"];
        cell.categoryNameLabel.text = [self getCategoryNameForCategory:categoryID];
        [cell.collectionView reloadData];
        return cell;
}
```

The collectionView delegates which is inside the tableview cell.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
        return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return _booksArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *identifier = @"bookCollectionViewCell";

        BookCollectionViewCell *cell = (BookCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
       dict = _booksArray[indexPath.item];
        NSString *imgString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.valmeeki.com/images/front_covers/%@.jpg",dict[@"id"]];
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]init];
        [prefs setObject:imgString forKey:@"bookcoverimg"];
        [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgString]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nik_bg_01.png"]];

        cell.costLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rs %@",[dict[@"price"] stringValue]];

        cell.titleLabel.text = dict[@"title"];

        cell.authoLabel.text = dict[@"authorName"];
        return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
        [prefs setObject:dict[@"title"] forKey:@"booktitle"];
        [prefs setObject:dict[@"authorName"] forKey:@"authorname"];
        [prefs setObject:dict[@"numDownloads"] forKey:@"bookdownloads"];
        [prefs setObject:dict[@"rating"] forKey:@"bookratings"];
        [prefs setObject:dict[@"price"] forKey:@"bookprice"];
        [prefs setObject:dict[@"synopsis"] forKey:@"booksynopsis"];
        [prefs setObject:dict[@"id"] forKey:@"bookid"];
        NSLog(@"%@",dict[@"title"]);
 SideMenuCategories *monitorMenuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideMenuCategories"];

        [self presentViewController:monitorMenuViewController animated:NO completion:nil];


}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? "I can't present another viewcontroller" doesn't explain much.

Comment: When i try to present a viewcontroller from the tableviewcell it show an error the storyboard property is not an object of tableviewcell

Comment: No one can say anything about your problem until you provide the code you wrote to achieve this.

Comment: Hi halileohalilei i have edited my question please help me !

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have fixed that issue !!

```
typedef void(^categorycallback)();
```

Give this code in your tableviewcell header

```
 Viewcontrollertobecalled *getcall = [[Viewcontrollertobecalled alloc] init];
        [getcall callthehome];
        if(self.callback)
        {
                self.callback();

        }
```

Add this code in the didselectrow of the tableview in tableviewcell.m

Catch the call back in the Viewcontroller class and give your code to present your viewcontroller .

```
   cell.callback = ^(){
                NavigationViewStore *questionnaireNavController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationViewStore"];
                               [questionnaireNavController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
                HomeViewController *qvc = (HomeViewController *)[questionnaireNavController topViewController];

               [self presentViewController:questionnaireNavController animated:NO completion:nil];
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Write Delegate methods for tableviewcell then set this delegate to view controller then pass the collectionview item selection message to view controller through the delegate methods you have implemented on the viewcontroller

declare the below protocol methods on your subclassed tableViewcell as a delegate method

```
-(void)tableViewcell:(id)sender didSelectCollectionItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexpath*)path;
```

with the help of the above method you can pass the selected indexpath to the viewController

Comment: How to pass the collectionview item selection message to viewcontroller ?? I tried putting break point in tableview methods on the didselect of collectionview .

Answer (score 0):

In your `CategoryTableViewCell` implementation, the method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` contains this line of code:

```
[self presentViewController:monitorMenuViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Here, `self` refers to your `CategoryTableViewCell`, which is not a subclass of `UIViewController`, therefore you can't really present anything on it. What you **can** do is, however, you can access the `UITableView` that contains your `CategoryTableViewCell`, and then access the `UIViewController` (or `UITableViewController`) holding it.

Something of this sort should work:

```
UITableView *tableView = self.superview.superview;
UIViewController *viewController = tableView.dataSource;
[viewController presentViewController:monitorMenuViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And please note that Apple can change the view hierarchy at anytimes, so in the upcoming versions of iOS, `self.superview.superview` might not give you the `UITableView` containing your cell. So this is a messy way of doing this, but it shouldn't cause any problem for the current version of iOS.